# BackboneJS Significance of Model/Collection urlRoot/URL

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

Let's say I have a Person model/collection as below;

```
define([
    'base/BaseModel'
], function(BaseModel) {
    var Person = BaseModel.extend({
        idAttribute: "personId",
        urlRoot: "manapp/person/",
        defaults: {
            "personId": null
        }
    return Person;
});

define([
    'base/BaseCollection',
    'model/Person'
], function(BaseCollection, Person) {
    var PersonCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
        url: "manapp/person",
        model: Person
    });
    return PersonCollection;
});
```

As you can see, I have a urlRoot/url attribute in model/collection.

My question is what exactly is the significance of specifying the values for this attribute? Is it only for the corresponding REST resource? If yes, is it only for the GET operation ? Also when exactly do you use the model and collection for them ?

Answer (score 1):

The urlRoot and url define the server paths to which the request is sent.

Edit: from the Backbone docs:

url:

> Returns the relative URL where the model's resource would be located
>   on the server. If your models are located somewhere else, override
>   this method with the correct logic.

urlRoot:

> Specify a urlRoot if you're using a model outside of a collection, to
>   enable the default url function to generate URLs based on the model
>   id. "[urlRoot]/id" Normally, you won't need to define this.

When you are using a back end MVC framework such as Laravel that implements a REST api, you can define the path in the router and handle the request to this path from a controller object.
I'll use Laravel as illustration, because this makes it clear.

When you define for example:

```
urlRoot: "/api_v1/entities/parents"
```

Laravel implements 'resourceful' controllers that can handle the different REST calls that are sent to a specific urlRoot on the server:

```
Route::resource('entities/parents', 'ParentsController');
```

Where the 'ParentsController' implements the set of methods that handle the different REST calls that can occur.

'GET' is not the only HTTP verb that you can use, but also 'POST', 'PUT' or 'DELETE'.

In Backbone: 
For 'GET', you call 'fetch()' on the object.
For 'POST', you call 'save()' on the object.
For 'DELETE', you call 'destroy()' on the object.
For 'PUT', you call 'save()' on the object, but after the fetched model has been updated. For example:

```
    var parent_model = new Parent_model({'id': 1}); 
    parent_model.fetch(); 
    parent_model.set('parent_name', 'some_parent'); 
    parent_model.save();
```

In the above example, a 'PUT' request is sent to the following path:

```
/api_v1/entities/parents/1
```

The controller implements a function that handles the REST call on the server like this:

```
public function update($id){ //Update code db here };
```

Aside from these standard REST calls, Laravel also implements an 'index' method, which doesn't take an id as parameter, and handles a generic 'GET' request.
I tend to use this for fetching collections from the server:
For example, the index() method for parents would return all parents, and does not work on one specific parent record.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Kim Gysen's answer focuses on the server-side; I think you may be asking about the client-side differences between `url` and `urlRoot`, and how they operate on Models vs Collections.

You specify a `Model.urlRoot` to override the default url of the collection. The [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) explain it pretty well, but basically, the URL that Backbone will call to operate on your model is constructed by default as:

- `[collection.url]/[collection.id]/[model.url]/[model.id]`

That works especially well for models that are part of a "parent" collection, as:

- `/documents/8/notes/2`

Now if you are operating on a model that is "standalone" rather than part of a collection, you specify a `Model.urlRoot`, so that the URL is constructed as:

- `[model.urlRoot]/[model.id]`

In all likelihood, you only really need to specify a Collection.url. If you do NOT specify a `url` or `urlRoot` on your model, and you specify a collection url of `manapp/person`, then Backbone will retrieve your collection from:

- `GET /manapp/person`, and expect a list of `Person` models

Operating on an individual model would then be

- **Create**: `POST /manapp/person/:id`; data payload is JSON of new `person` record
- **Read**: `GET /manapp/person/:id`
- **Update**: `PUT /manapp/person/:id`; data payload is JSON of updated `person` record (including non-dirty attributes!)
- **Delete**: `DELETE /manapp/person/:id`